# Ошибка image "pyimage2" doesn't exist при использовании библиотеки Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Так и не могу решить проблему. Мне нужно запустить программу, чтобы на главном экране за место фона была фотография, а прямо на ней располагались кнопки. Предупредите меня, если мой вопрос не оригинален и оповестите меня о каких-то принципах гугла, о которых я мог не знать. Долгое время я разбираюсь с кодом, однако не могу понять, в чем причина. Столкнулся с данной ошибкой не первый раз, однако в ходе безуспешных попыток решить данную проблему вернулся снова к этой ошибке. Пробовал ответы со StackOverflow, но они не принесли мне пользы, поскольку я столкнулся с тем, что в прошлом виде моего кода применялся метод grid, а не pack. Пришлось разбираться с этим - и на данном моменте я решил все-таки написать на данный сайт, ожидая помощи от Вас. Благодарю за внимание!

Ошибка: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Код:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
def show_image(path):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root["bg"] = "black"
    root.title("Torchery")#Название окна
    root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.85)#регулировка прозрачности
    root.geometry('600x500')

    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

    tk.Button(root, text="Калькулятор", command=lambda: print("Привет, Tkinter!"))
    tk.Button(text='Соцсеть', command=show_image(path).quit).place(x=260, y=250)
    tk.Button(text='Настройки и параметры', command=show_image(path).quit).place(x=260, y=250)

    lbl = Label(root.mainloop(), text='Выключение...')
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

    root.mainloop()

show_image('C:/я слышал/что/путь/нужно/скрывать/Скачать-картинки-на-рабочий-стол-с-хорошим-качеством-красивые-крутые-6.jpg')
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы не слышали, что Python не любит кириллицу в путях.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Попробовал ваши рекомендации. Вопрос оказался занимательнее, чем я думал: ошибка все та же.

Comment: Прошу прощения: я был немного невнимателен, когда спрашивал Вас. Мне потребуется некоторое время, чтобы оповестить Вас о последующих успехах, ведь судя по вашему совету - проблема в том, что имя пользователя на моем компьютере стоит на кириллице. Для входа в учетную запись Майкрософт я не знаю параметры входа, которые нужно будет спросить у моего отца. Если что - я напишу вам о последующих проблемах. Об успехах не напишу, ведь благодарность не принята в форме таких сообщений в StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Я решил эту ошибку
Извлекая все функции из tkintera с помощью *, ты так же извлекаешь `tkinter.Image`, что конфликтует с from PIL import Image

Решается: `from PIL import Image as I`

Answer (score 1):

Решение есть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800007/why-photoimages-dont-exist

Оно странное, но интересное. Вместо `Tk()` нужно писать `TopLevel()`. Причина - указанная строка создает ещё один инстанс Tk, а это не очень нравится самой Tk.

Comment: tk.Toplevel(), я прав? Я столкнулся с ошибкой invalid syntax, что мне выводит путь, по которому расположен файл с проектом. Ошибка выглядит таким образом:
>>> python "d:/Рабочий стол/testbrez.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python "d:/Рабочий стол/testbrez.py"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 

ранее я удалил первую строку кода, однако это не принесло результатов.

Answer (score 0):

*Вообще для создания графического интерфейса лучше использовать* **PyQt5**

*Потому что вас поломают менеджеры размещения в* **tkinter**

*Я не знаю почему работает размещение изображения в tkinter.Label как в приведённом ниже скрипте, но так это работает*

```
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests


URL = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/4000/0*-jWOgP1Dh0sF8Uxa.jpg'


class TkinterApplication(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.configure(bg='black')
        self.title('Torchery')
        self.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)#регулировка прозрачности
        self.geometry('705x500')

        self.panel = Label(self)
        self.panel.place(x=0, y=0)

        Button(self, text="поменять фон", command=self.show_background_image).place(x=610, y=475)

    def show_background_image(self):
        content = requests.get(URL).content
        pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
        # pil_image.thumbnail((600, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        modified_image = pil_image.resize((700, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(modified_image)
        #######################################################################
        self.panel.configure(image=image)
        self.panel.image = image
        #######################################################################

def main():
    application = TkinterApplication()
    application.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А на счёт ошибки  image "pyimage2" doesn't exist примерно значит не подготовленное изображение или не туда впихиваете.

Comment: Ах да если вы хотите создать другое окно т.е. модальное то используйте TopLevel